# VBA obtaining checkbox values from userform

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I'm having trouble obtaining values from checkboxes of a userform. The problem I have is that the userform creates a variable number of checkboxes based on a value from a sheet. The code for this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim Teller As Long
Dim chkBox As MSForms.CheckBox

Teller = 1
LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LastRow
    If Worksheets("Sheet").Cells(i, 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet").Range("S1").Value Then
        Set chkBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox_" & Teller)
        chkBox.Caption = Worksheets("Sheet").Cells(i, 9).Value
        chkBox.Left = 5
        chkBox.Top = 25 + ((Teller - 1) * 20)
        Teller = Teller + 1
    End If
Next i    
End Sub
```

So this creates a number of checkboxes named CheckBox_1, CheckBox_2 etc.
The problem is when I try to get the value for CheckBox_1 in the module, CheckBox_1 has not yet been created so I'm not able to use it.

```
Dim x as String
With UserForm4
     .Show
     x = .CheckBox_1
     MsgBox (x)
     End
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to loop through .Controls the textbox is not a property on your form.

Comment: Won't **necessarily** have to loop through the controls - `x = .Controls("CheckBox_1").Value` will work if the OP knows that they want the first one.  (But obviously `x = .Controls("CheckBox_" & i).Value` can be used if they do need to loop through.)